# Invalid datetime format in Pardot query

Tags: pardot

I'm trying to read some records through the Pardot API, for example the [visitor page view](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/visitor-page-view-v5.html)

If I'm not using any filters, it works just fine and I get some records. I copied the `createdAt` right from one result record: 2022-02-28T14:11:17+00:00

Now I want to make another API call, but this time with a filter, but it fails:

`...&createdAtAfter=2022-02-28T14:11:17+00:00`

> {'code': 51, 'message': 'Invalid parameter: Parameter createdAtAfter is invalid. Invalid date time value'}

Why am I getting this error message? I've tried several datetime formats, shorter (only date) or longer (millisecs), older or today, with or without T or ' ', Z or +00:00, neither worked.

For this error code the docs says "Change the object type to one of the allowed types.", that doesn't help.

The general docs also says "DateTime    ISO 8601 formatted date and time (including timezone offset)." which also didn't help since my timestamp string is in valid ISO format.

Sadly I cannot find any examples using datetime filter. Does it need any escaping or quoting or prefix?

Comment: Not in V4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494946/pardot-visit-query-api-generic-query-not-available . Check with Pardot support if it's available in V5.

Comment: @identigral Well I'm getting the same message for v4 API too.

Comment: This question is not limited to the visitor page view. It was just an example. We might use any other object and filter. I asked the correct datetime format and the error message I received. If the format I've tried is fine, but it doesn't work only for the view & field I've tried then I can report that.

Comment: Date/time format of a filter value is based on [GNU Date/Time syntax](https://github.com/pardot/api-docs/blob/0d1bf4c26112b15477411512bd2da569023fbda0/docs/kb/api-version-4/visitors.md). (This link renders faster in non-Chrome browsers). Open an issue on GH if you can't get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your format was right "2022-02-28T14:11:17+00:00", but... Pardot requires UrlEncoded dateformat, so the "+" needs to be encoded as %2B.

The other format that was offered to you worked because it had an american timezone with negative offset - which doesn't requires to be UrlEncoded.
(+ is a space if not encoded while - is just a -)

Comment: OMG indeed. :D I'm using Python requests and not a library that takes care for the encoding, totally forgot that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For V3/V4, you need to use the DateTime format: `2019-01-01 00:00:00`. Keep in mind that the TimeZone will be in the TimeZone of the User and you can't set it through the API.

For V5, you need to use the DateTime format: `2021-09-18T15:50:00-04:00`, noting the TimeZone is specified within the value.

Take a look at the Pardot API Samples that are found in Postman collections. They have the date & time in the correct format for both V3/4 and V5 (well, at least our collection does).

Here's a link to our collection, I hope it helps you out! https://www.postman.com/sercante/workspace/pardot/collection/8542420-6f4eb4ac-584d-4123-a1aa-74d5cbede5cc

Comment: Thanks, answer edited to include examples of the datetime formats.